# Navigation Controller with TabBarController in App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to make a tableview with two views, the tableview controller and the otherView controller.  The tableview needs a navigation controller to get to a third view when a cell is clicked.  I tried using the code below in my AppDelegate.m but it just creates the tableview with the navigation controller.  Any suggestions on how I should edit this to get the tabview working as well?  Thanks!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

AJBTableViewController *masterViewController = [[AJBTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

_mainTabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_navigationController, otherViewController, nil];

[_window addSubview:_mainTabBar.view];

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab bar controller should be the root view controller of the app, not the navigation controller of the first tab bar item.

Comment: Thanks for the quick repsonse!  if I change just that I only get a blank screen.  ive tried a couple combinations of setting the rootviewcontroller and the way I initialize the navigation controller and Im just not sure what to do.

Comment: Seems you are on the right track :) Best is to do all in storyboard and just `return YES;` in your app delegate call.

Comment: I wish haha, I inherited the work from someone else and am finishing it for that same person so I have to do it programmatically

Comment: I understand, but still I think you don't "have to". You can refactor intelligently ;-).

Answer (score 1):

```
_mainTabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_navigationController, otherViewController, nil];
[_window addSubview:_mainTabBar.view];
```

Instead this code, you try below code:

```
UITabBarController *tbC = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tbC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_navigationController,otherViewController, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = tbC;
```

and delete

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid error, I never allocated an instance of the tabbar controller, Mundi is right, making the rootviewcontroller the tabbarcontroller is the way to go.